# How to declare variable in angular/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new in Angular/Typescript, so i tried a folow a tutorial and when he created a service he set the url as below

```
 baseUrl = 'https://localhost:44351/api/member/';
```

and i read before that variables in Typescritpt are declared with var and let, so when i tired to updated the code to  :

```
  var baseUrl = "https://localhost:44351/api/member/";
```

it gives me an error compilation, isn't that how we suppose to declare variable ?

Comment: Could you add more information on the context ? Are you trying to add a variable in a function or in a class ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said you are trying to create a service, i'm assuming your are defining this variable in a class.

When declaring *class-wide* variable, ( called properties )  you don't need the `let` keyword. Instead, you want to define it as `private`, `public` or `protected`.

In you case, I feel like a `private` variable would be more suitable. In that case, you can do something lile this.

```
export class MyService {
   private baseUrl = 'https://localhost:44351/api/member/';
   /* ... */
}
```

You can then access this variable using the `this` keyword, inside the service functions.

```
export class MyService {
   private baseUrl = 'https://localhost:44351/api/member/';
   /* ... */

   public getTheBaseUrl(): any {
     return this.baseUrl;
   }
}
```

Here, I've used a getter to demonstrate, but you could use the same syntax to call an XmlHTTPRequest for example.

Also, since this is an url and very unlikely to change, you can use the keyword `readonly` which prevent it from being alter elsewhere in the code.

```
export class MyService {
   private readonly baseUrl = 'https://localhost:44351/api/member/';
   /* ... */

   public getTheBaseUrl(): any {
     return this.baseUrl;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks now i get it, could you please tell when to use ":" or "=" and " " "  or " ' "

Comment: @user1187282 You use `:` to define the type of the variable. In our case we don't need it because we initialized it to a static value, which is a string. If we didn't we would want to define it as string ( `baseUrl: string;` )  and the assign it else where in the code ( `this.baseUrl = '...';` ) . As for the quote it does not really matther.